# Javascript setInterval() not working on function call

Tags: javascript

I need to refresh a div on 3 sec so I tried a setInterval method as follows using javaScript:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function hello(){
alert("vannallo");
}

function myFunction() {
    setInterval(hello(), 3000);
}

</script>
```

This is not working, But when I tried like thje following it works:

```
function myFunction() {
        setInterval(function hello(){
    alert("vannallo");
    }, 3000);
}
```

I need to work setInterval continuosly on my first buttonclick , How can I acheive it? Please help guys!!

Comment: Search a little bit harder on SO for the answer to this question, which has come up many times. Hint: specifying a function is different from calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't passing your function to `setInterval` but what it returns (that is `undefined`).

Change

```
setInterval(hello(), 3000);
```

to

```
setInterval(hello, 3000);
```